# Regex to find compensations in text

Tags: python-3.x, regex, text

I need to find mentions of compensations in emails. I am new to regex. Please see below the approach I am using.

`sample_text = "Rate – $115k/yr. or $55/hr. - $60/hr"`

My python code to find this,

```
impor re
PATTERN = r'((\$|\£) [0-9]*)|((\$|\£)[0-9]*)'
print(re.findall(PATTERN,sample_text))
```

The matches I am getting is

`[('', '', '$115', '$'), ('', '', '$55', '$'), ('', '', '$60', '$')]`

Expected match

`["$115k/yr","$55/hr","$60/hr"]`

Also the $ sign can be written as USD. How do I handle this in the same regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
[$£]\d+[^.\s]*
```

- `[$£]` Match either `$` or `£`
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `[^.\s]*` Repeat 0+ times matching any char except `.` or a whitespace

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TcHwco/1)

```
import re
sample_text = "Rate – $115k/yr. or $55/hr. - $60/hr"
PATTERN = r'[$£]\d+[^.\s]*'
print(re.findall(PATTERN,sample_text))
```

Output

```
['$115k/yr', '$55/hr', '$60/hr']
```

---

If there must be a `/` present, you might also use

```
[$£]\d+[^\s/.]*/\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b8t0rp/1)

Comment: With slight more modifications and extension, I was able to create a regex to counter my problems. This was a good starting point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like:

```
[$£]\d+[^.]+
```

---

```
>>> PATTERN = '[$£]\d+[^.]+
>>> print(re.findall(PATTERN,sample_text))
['$115k/yr', '$55/hr', '$60/hr']
```

- `[$£]` matches "$" or a "£"
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `[^.]+` matches everything that's not a "."

Comment: For another sample_text, it returns 
`['$65 $70 per hour Max  any visa will work except CPT and STEM OPT and WebEx call interview is must']`

Comment: This returns the following matches too,
`['$68-70/hr (Max)\nMinimum Qualifications/requirements:\n We need min of 6-8 years of IT profile']`

Comment: `[^.]+` is way too broad, you probably want to restrict it to something like a single word.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses in your regex cause the engine to report the contents of each parenthesized subexpression. You can use non-grouping parentheses `(?:...)` to avoid this, but of course, your expression can be rephrased to not have any parentheses at all:

```
PATTERN = r'[$£]\s*\d+'
```

Notice also how I changed the last quantifier to a `+` -- your attempt would also find isolated currency symbols with no numbers after them.

To point out the hopefully obvious, `\s` matches whitespace and `\s*` matches an arbitrary run of whitespace, including none at all; and `\d` matches a digit.

If you want to allow some text after the extracted match, add something like `(?:/\w+)?` to allow for a slash and one single word token as an optional expression after the main match. (Maybe adorn that with `\s*` on both sides of the slash, too.)